# Using model for prediction

Tags: r, rstudio, prediction, predict

I am trying to predict new dates using a model I have created.
The first question is to build a model to study the relationship b/w date and positive variable from 2020-03-16 to 2020-03-29. 
I have used below code:

```
Covid = Covid[, c(1,3)]
head(Covid)
subset = Covid$date>="2020-03-16" & Covid$date <= "2020-03-29"`
Covid_sub = Covid[subset,]`
M1 = lm(positive ~ date, data = Covid_sub)
```

Then I needed to predict new dates using the model
the dates are 2020-03-30 to 2020-04-08
it's only 10 dates, but I'm always getting rows 11 -24. Is that correct and I just have to interpret data from the first 10 rows? Here is the code I used for it

```
subset2 = Covid$date>="2020-03-30" & Covid$date <= "2020-04-08" 
Covid_sub2 = Covid[subset2,]
predict(Covid = subset2,M1, interval = "confidence")

   fit        lwr       upr
11 115947.657  70520.579 161374.73
12 105766.435  61302.585 150230.29
13  95585.213  51940.289 139230.14
14  85403.991  42425.441 128382.54
15  75222.769  32750.860 117694.68
16  65041.547  22910.783 107172.31
17  54860.325  12901.174  96819.48
18  44679.103   2719.952  86638.25
19  34497.881  -7632.883  76628.65
20  24316.659 -18155.250  66788.57
21  14135.437 -28843.113  57113.99
22   3954.215 -39690.709  47599.14
23  -6227.007 -50690.857  38236.84
24 -16408.229 -61835.306  29018.85
```

Here is the data

```
     date      positive
1   2020-04-08  423164
2   2020-04-07  392594
3   2020-04-06  361331
4   2020-04-05  332308
5   2020-04-04  305755
6   2020-04-03  271988
7   2020-04-02  239099
8   2020-04-01  210816
9   2020-03-31  184683
10  2020-03-30  160530
11  2020-03-29  139061
12  2020-03-28  118234
13  2020-03-27  99413
14  2020-03-26  80735
15  2020-03-25  63928
16  2020-03-24  51954
17  2020-03-23  42152
18  2020-03-22  31879
19  2020-03-21  23197
20  2020-03-20  17033
21  2020-03-19  11719
22  2020-03-18  7730
23  2020-03-17  5722
24  2020-03-16  4019
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here. Perhaps the main problem is that you are trying to do a simple linear regression on an exponential growth curve. This will give terrible predictions.

Anyway, as a coding exercise, you could proceed like this. First make sure your dates are all in a date format rather than character or factor. This will ensure you are getting your subsetting right.

```
Covid$date <- as.POSIXct(Covid$date)
Covid_sub <- Covid[which(Covid$date >= as.POSIXct("2020-03-16") &
                         Covid$date <= as.POSIXct("2020-03-29")), ]
```

Now we can produce the model:

```
M1 <- lm(positive ~ date, data = Covid_sub)
```

To get predictions for dates that weren't in the model, we create a vector of dates we want. We feed these as a list or data frame to the `newdata` parameter of `predict`:

```
new_dates <- seq(as.POSIXct("2020-03-30"), as.POSIXct("2020-04-08"), by = "day")
pred <- predict(M1, newdata = list(date = new_dates), interval = "confidence")

pred
#>         fit      lwr      upr
#> 1  125704.7 109460.4 141948.9
#> 2  135885.9 117932.9 153838.9
#> 3  146067.1 126367.2 165767.0
#> 4  156248.3 134772.6 177724.0
#> 5  166429.5 143155.8 189703.3
#> 6  176610.8 151521.5 201700.0
#> 7  186792.0 159873.3 213710.7
#> 8  196973.2 168213.8 225732.6
#> 9  207154.4 176545.0 237763.8
#> 10 217335.7 184868.6 249802.7
```

Now we can see how poor this fit is by plotting it against the actual data:

```
plot(Covid$date, Covid$positive)
lines(new_dates, pred[,1])
lines(new_dates, pred[,2], col = "red", lty = 2)
lines(new_dates, pred[,3], col = "red", lty = 2)
```

[image]

You may wish to consider taking the `log` of `positive` and repeating the regression. You can the plot the `exp` of the predictions against the original `positive` results. I think you'll be pleased with the results.